# rerendering apex:inputText onchange to incorporate different styles

Tags: visualforce, rerender, inputtext

Is it possible to rerender an apex:inputText field immediately when the user changes the value of the field? In my application the form's input fields look different if they are already populated (true in some cases) compared to when they are empty or need to be filled out. I have tried using

```
<apex:actionSupport event="onchange" reRender="<outputPanel-ID>"/>
```

and

```
<apex:actionSupport event="onblur" reRender="<outputPanel-ID>"/>
```

within my apex:outputPanel but this did not change anything.

Comment: Doing a server round-trip each time the user changes the field value may lead to poor user experience. Can you make the changes you need in client-side JavaScript?

Comment: I could write a script, I was hoping to handle this with out of the box features.

Comment: Without seeing your code, it would be hard to know more about what's wrong. Generally speaking, it is possible, though not advisable, to do so.